# Could setInterval wakes up phone?

Tags: javascript, mobile, setinterval, wakeup

Is this possible that setInterval() doesnt allow my phone to turn off? If I on my website on my phone after 15 seconds screen will fade out and turn off. Few of my viewers says that on their phones screen will never fade out. Why is that? I have two setIntervals on my website. Maybe it is setInterval wakes up some phones? Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt it, otherwise most websites would be causing this issue for them.   Maybe it's what your doing in the setInterval, are you getting geolocation or something like that.

Comment: There is hundreds different phone models with different OS with different browsers. And it is totally depends on user made settings on their devices. Is there is some phones that keep screen on if something happening on web page, may be...